# Why I don't get segmentation fault when using argc and argv?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have an OpenGL program with my main with 2 parameters 
I am compiling with xCode on macOS

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
...
glutInit(&argc, argv);
```

I studied that if i don't compile with a.out and 2 values after I should get segmentation fault but I'm not getting it compiling without those values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The segmentation fault to which you are alluding is a particular manifestation of program *undefined behaviour*.

But undefined behaviour is exactly that: you don't know what's going to happen.

Which is why you need to check the value of `argc` before reading any of `argv`.

Comment: I don't understand . Why can I use glutInit(&agrc , argv) without declaring argc and argv ?

Comment: They're declared as arguments to `main`, meaning they have the scope of local variables in `main` ... are you missing some relevant code?

Comment: In Xcode I do not declare them and i don't get Errors

Comment: @Jatos: What are you talking about? They are there right in *your* code's main function parameter definition.

Comment: @Bathsheba I am using Xcode to run my code. So I don't have any ./a.out... How does main get those parameters ?

Comment: @datenwolf how does main get those parameters ?

Comment: @Jatos: After the operating system loaded a new program image it then starts the process by jumping to the so called *entry point*. The entry point is essentially a function that returns nothing and takes no parameters, i.e. `void _start(void)`. This function start then does some housekeeping. Among other things it retrieves the command line parameters (the actual buffer has already been allocated by the operating system) and at last calls `main` with those.